# error using WHILE condition bash

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, do-while

i'm learning while statement on bash linux. but i've got error when running this one. anyone can help me?

$ nano file1.sh

```
#!/bin/csh
set i=$#argv
while   ($i)
echo –n $argv[$i]
@ i--
end
```

$ ./file1.sh My nam is Jack

Comment: csh is not bash, or even remotely compatible with bash; it's a completely different shell.

Comment: i'm typo, @CharlesDuffy. how to fix above?

Comment: First, we need to know which shell you want to know how to write code for. If you want to write code for bash, we need to take all the csh syntax out of your script.

Comment: (btw, see http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt discussing why csh shouldn't be used).

Comment: `$#argv`, for instance, **doesn't actually mean anything in bash at all**. Neither does `set`. Neither does `@` at the beginning of a line. As in, the place to start is with a reference teaching the language; what we help with here is specific, well-identified, isolated problems with code samples built in [mcve] form -- but you've got a whole bunch of unrelated issues mushed together.

Comment: ...by the way, the reference I personally recommend is the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). The StackOverflow [tag wiki for bash](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) is also a good source of material and helpful links.

Comment: (well, `set` *does* have a meaning in bash, but it's unrelated to assigning values to variables, unless one counts positional parameters and/or shell behavioral flags as "variables").